# unable to reload rabbitmq ssl cache

Tags: docker, ssl, rabbitmq, erlang, rabbitmqctl

I'm having problems reloading my rabbitmq ssl certs when they get renewed. The core of my setup is as follows:

- vps running the rabbitmq [community edition docker container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/)
- ssl certs provisioned using letsencrypt on the vps, with the certs available to the docker image via a mounted folder
- auto-renewal configured by mounting a folder that gets bound to `/plugins/rabbitmq_management-{rmq-version}/priv/www` in the docker container, and specifying the `--webroot-path` as that folder. This allows the renewal to work without shutting down the server because the `/priv/www` folder is where cowboy serves static assets from

The problem now is that even with the renewal successful, the server seems to not pick up the changed ssl certs unless the docker container is restarted. For this problem the closest I've found to a possible solution is [this recommendation](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/AdkDZhmYtAA/m/60lq77fuBQAJ) to clear the certs cache, but when I try that command the error message I get is this: `unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on {cluser-name}.localdomain: nxdomain (non-existing domain)`. I haven't found a solution to this problem yet. I've seen [this suggestion](https://community.netwitness.com/t5/netwitness-knowledge-base/rabbitmq-is-not-starting-non-existing-domain-in-rsa-netwitness/ta-p/6323) to check the contents of the `/etc/hosts/` file, and the contents of mine differ from the contents shown in that blog article. Specifically mine simply shows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
...
```

without the `localhost.localdomain` parts shown in the article. I'm stumped beyond this point. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just to confirm, you are having the error of "…nxdomain…" when running the command `rabbitmqctl eval 'ssl:clear_pem_cache().'` in the shell where RabbitMQ is installed?

Comment: @YanValuyskiy yes that's correct.

Comment: Can you please check the hostname of your container and check rabbitmq logs hostname it is started with. Those should be the same otherwise you might see the error. The script `rabbitmqctl` uses hostname to connect to Erlang node and it should be basically the same that RabbitMQ uses for start, but in this situation it uses different name. Do you mind to provide docker inspect and some logs from container start with RabbitMQ information?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@localhost eval 'ssl:clear_pem_cache().'
```